# Bootstrapping is not applied when routing on node js

Tags: html, node.js, router

I'm now trying to specify the path through get and post on the node server. When html is opened, bootstrapping works well.But running through routing will run without bootstrapping.

how do i do?

```js
// 켈린더 메인 메뉴
$(function() {
    // Easy pie charts
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 header: {
  left: 'prev,next',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
 },
 theme: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        if (title) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: allDay
                },
                true // make the event "stick"
            );
        }
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
    drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

        // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

        // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

        // assign it the date that was reported
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

        // render the event on the calendar
        // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            $(this).remove();
        }

    },
 editable: true,
 // US Holidays
 events: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic'

 });
});

// 켈린더 사이드 메뉴
$('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

    // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
    // it doesn't need to have a start or end
    var eventObject = {
        title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
    };

    // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
    $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999999999,
        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });

});
```

```css
#external-events {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #eee;
    text-align: left;
    }
    
#external-events h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 1em;
    }
    
.external-event { /* try to mimick the look of a real event */
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    background: #3366CC;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .85em;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 99999999;
    }
    
#external-events p {
    margin: 1.5em 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #666;
    }
    
#external-events p input {
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Time Matrix Scheduling System</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- jQuery UI -->
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="vendors/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <!-- styles -->
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="css/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <!-- Logo -->
          <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="index.html">Time Matrix Scheduling System</a></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="input-group form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
                        </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInUp">
                    <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html">Logout</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="sidebar content-box" style="display: block;">
          <ul class="nav">
            <!-- Main menu -->
            <li><a href="index.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="calendar.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="stats.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></i> Statistics (Charts)</a></li>
            <li><a href="tables.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="buttons.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></i> Buttons</a></li>
            <li><a href="editors.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Editors</a></li>
            <li><a href="forms.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i> Forms</a></li>
            <li class="submenu">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Pages
                <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
              </a>
              <!-- Sub menu -->
              <ul>
                <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="signup.html">Signup</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">

        <div class="content-box-large">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <!-- <div class="col-md-2">
           <div id='external-events'>
                                     <h4>Draggable Events</h4>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 1</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 2</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 3</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 4</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 5</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 6</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 7</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 8</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 9</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 10</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 11</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 12</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 13</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 14</div>
                                     <div class='external-event'>My Event 15</div>
                                     <p>
                                     <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' /> <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
                                     </p>
                                    </div>
          </div> -->
              <div class="col-md-7">
                <div id='calendar'></div>
                <hr>
                <p>test line</p>
                <table width="100%" border="1">
                  <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>title</th>
                    <th>place</th>
                    <th>start_time</th>
                    <th>end_time</th>
                  </tr>
                    <% data.forEach(function(item, index){ %>
                    <tr>
                      <td><%= item.id%></td>
                      <td><%= item.title%></td>
                      <td><%= item.place%></td>
                      <td><%= item.start_time%></td>
                      <td><%= item.end_time%></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }); %>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="copy text-center">
        Copyright 2014 <a href='#'>Website</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery UI -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="vendors/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>
  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
  <script src="js/calendar.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

----------------------- add server source --------------------------------------

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var router = express.Router();
var dbconfig = require('./config/db_config.js');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('calendar.html','utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('readefile error');
    } else {
      connection.query('select * from datework', function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('error : ', err.message);
        } else {
          // res.send(data.toString());
          res.send(ejs.render(data,{
            data: results
          }));
          // var datatest = JSON.parse(data);
          // res.json(dayatest[req.params.start_time]);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxfbP.png)

Comment: So, what are you doing ?

Comment: I simply want to express it in html via the node server. I tried to apply a bootstrap to html but I do not have a bootstrap UI ...
However, if you only run html instead of through the server, the bootstrap UI will be applied well.
There are so many codes that it will be cumbersome to upload ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Express docs [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) explain how to serve static files. This is the most likely reason why you can see bootstrap statically but not when served by Express.

`app.use(express.static('public'))`

where 'public' is the name of the directory holding your client-side files.

The path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process. If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`

Comment: I had to create a public folder and put the js and the bootstrap file.
Thanks!